Linkedin OAUTH call v2 with r_liteprofile SCOPE does not work
    const scope = 'r_liteprofile,r_emailaddress,w_member_social';  // Request both posting and profile access
    const state = uuidv4();
    sessionStorage.setItem('linkedin_oauth_state', state);
    const linkedInAuthUrl = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(
        REDIRECT_URI
    )}&state=${state}&scope=${encodeURIComponent(scope)}`;

    // Open a popup window
    const width = 600;
    const height = 600;
    const left = window.screen.width / 2 - width / 2;
    const top = window.screen.height / 2 - height / 2;

    window.open(
        linkedInAuthUrl,
        'LinkedInAuth',
        `width=${width},height=${height},top=${top},left=${left}`
    );

Linkedin Error
OAuth 2.0 Scopes
I can't find any way to add r_liteprofile into the scope, and I call it in I get an error.

The r_liteprofile scope is deprecated. You can only request the scopes available in your LinkedIn app settings. So in your case it's profile and email.
In addition, in LinkedIn's documentation, they mention that it needs to be a URL-encoded, space-delimited list of member permissions your application is requesting on behalf of the user, and not a comma:

"URL-encoded, space-delimited list of member permissions your application is requesting on behalf of the user. These must be explicitly requested. For example, scope=liteprofile%20emailaddress%20w_member_social."

